# Limiting disc and memory cache sizes using NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiwebview

I have an app that uses `UIWebViews`. I am using `RNCachingURLProtocol` to cache pages for offline browsing. `RNCachingProtocol` uses `NSURLConnection` in requests. In my **AppDelegate** I have the following code:

```
NSUInteger cacheSizeInMemory = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
NSUInteger cacheSizeOnDisc = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeInMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeOnDisc diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

I have tested the `RNCachingProtocol` and confirmed that it does cache web content to disc. Since `RNCachingURLProtocol` uses `NSURLConnection`, am I to assume that my `UIWebView` objects will make use of the `NSURLCache` defined in my AppDelegate? Is there any clear way to test this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebView use shared url cache so yes, `[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];` sets cache that will be used by UIWebView.

The easiest to see this would be subclassing NSURLCache and do something in

```
-(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request;
```

method. Then set your subclass as shared cache and see for yourself.